# PhpStorm: how to apply WordPress security rules

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm, phpcs

How do I apply WordPress security rules on PHPCS using PhpStorm? In PhpStorm Inspection widow under Coding Standards dropdown I have the following:

```
WordPress
WordPress-Core
WordPress-Docs
WordPress-Extra
WordPress-VIP
PSR1
PSR2
PSR12
Sqiz
Custom
Zend
```

Which one should I select for security sniffing purpose? I could not find a suitable answer after Googling 2 for hours. I need to run the security ruleset on a plugin that I have developed. Please suggest.

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- PhpStorm version: 2017.1.3

Comment: Is there a designated WordPress security ruleset for Code Sniffer? I couldn't google it as well. What makes you think there is one?

Comment: I don't know of any either. But since CS tool has some dedicated rulesets available, I thought there might be one like this too. However, if it is not available, please advise me which one from the list should I pick up for sniffing purpose. Thank you!

Comment: From my experience (I am a PhpStorm support engineer), people usually use the first one, `Wordpress`, as it includes the underlying ones.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneMorozov. One question though. Which areas are usually treated as Security by this standard? Do we have a documentation of similar kinda thing available so that I get some idea?

Comment: @SubrataSarkar I think you better ask WordPress guys about that. I think they should know more abut own tool than PhpStorm support...